# indoor positioning based on arduino and ble?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, indoor-positioning-system

I need to track on about 500 boxes in warehouses, the trace should be in door and outdoor.
the accuracy is not so impotent -> 5-15 meters is enough .

warehouse size include the yard is about 40000 square fit.

i though of having 2 parts to my solution:
1) attach to each box a small device with BLE/arduino with battery that broadcast his unique name. - must be cheap and low power.

2) a network of arduino+ble devices that  each of them scan for every ble device his their area ( boxes ) , and send the data with Bluetooth to other BLE devices  all the way to command center that pars the data and calculate the position of each box,

the box moved frequently but in low speed(human speed).

can you please point me to available data? 
1)maybe there is better why to do it then using ble (nrf? radio? wifi? ) 
2)opensource library?
3)available solution? 
4) parts to use?

Thanks!!

Comment: These are pretty tough requirements to meet.  I suspect this is beyond the kind ofprogramming  problem you can solve with a simple question on StackOverflow.

Comment: I know.. I just looking for directions not implementation